# Example of a function $f(x) + f(y) > 2f(\frac{nx + y}{n + 1})$ where $n \ge 1$.

Tags: statistics

I'm looking for a function to help me prove something. Function should be defined on all non-negative real numbers and should be one-one. Also $f(0) = 0$ and $x > y \implies f(x) > f(y)$. I know that $f(x) = x^2$ works for $n = 1$, is there a function in terms of $n$ that works in general? Thanks!

Comment: Just a clarificiation, the condition is for when $x \ne y$ as when $x = y$ the left hand side is equal to right hand side.